# Filtering a list of objects by a child array in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have data that looks like this

```
[
  {id: 1234,
   Name: 'John',
   Tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']
  },
  {id: 1235,
   Name: 'Mike',
   Tags: ['tag1', 'tag3']
  }
]
```

I want to be able to type into a search bar and filter the data to search for related tags. There was a built in filter pipe for this in angular 1 but it looks like it has been removed in angular 2.  I've been looking into custom pipes but the only way I can think to do it is with a nested loop that loops over all of the objects then loops through the tags.  Am I thinking about this wrong.  Is there an easier way to do this or a built in function that would work for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use normal javascript APIs to get that behaviour:

```
data = [
  {id: 1234,
   Name: 'John',
   Tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']
  },
  {id: 1235,
   Name: 'Mike',
   Tags: ['tag1', 'tag3']
  }
];

filterDataByTag(searchTerm: string) {

   // filter the data array, based on some condition
   return this.data.filter(item => {

      // only include an item in the filtered results
      // if that item's Tags property includes the searchTerm
      // includes is a built in array method in ES2016
      return item.Tags.includes(searchTerm);
   });  
}
```

In my example, i'm harding coding the `data`, but you can adjust to suit your situation. The key point is the function returns a filtered list of the `data` based on the searchTerm, so you can just call this method each time you want to refresh your filtered list  *(for eg on the input event of your search field)*

Comment: The function could be simplified to: return this.data.filter(item => item.Tags.includes(searchTerm);

Answer (score 0):

You should reorganize data into a reverse index store :

```
export interface StoreData {
  Tag: string;
  Peoples: People[] = [];
}

const store: StoreData[] = [];

export interface People {
  id: number; 
  Name: string;
  Tags: string[];
}

loadPeopleStore(peoples: People) {
  peoples.forEach(p => {
    p.Tags.forEach(t => {
      let storeData = store.filter(d => d.Tag === t);
      if(storeData.length == 1) {
        storeData[0].Peoples.push(p);
      } else {
        store.push({Tag: t, Peoples[p]});
      }
    }
  }
}

initYourPipe() {
 let peoples: People[] =   [
    {id: 1234,
     Name: 'John',
     Tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']
    },
    {id: 1235,
     Name: 'Mike',
     Tags: ['tag1', 'tag3']
    }
  ]

  this.loadPeopleStore(peoples);


}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out!